# Swift Extensions for Collections

Tags: swift, protocols, sequences

I'm working on a framework to make it easier to work with Key Value Observing and I've defined a protocol for converting native Swift types to NSObject as follows:

```
public protocol NSObjectConvertible {
  func toNSObject () -> NSObject
}
```

Extending the builtin types was easy, simply defining the function to convert the given type to the appropriate NSObject:

```
extension Int8: NSObjectConvertible {
   public func toNSObject () -> NSObject {
     return NSNumber(char: self)
   }
}
```

When I got to the Array type, I hit a number of snags, which I tried to work out.  I didn't want to extend any array type, but only arrays whose element type was itself NSObjectConvertible.  And naturally, needed Array to itself conform to the protocol.

After hunting around on SO, it looks like extending the Array type itself is a little harder because it's generic, but extending SequenceType can be done.  Except that I can't *both* constrain the element type *and* declare its conformance to the protocol in the same declaration.

The following:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == NSObjectConvertible : NSObjectConvertible = {
   public func toNSObject () -> NSObject {
     return self.map() { return $0.toNSObject() }
   }
 }
```

Produces a compiler error:

> Expected '{' in extension

And the carat points to the ":" where I'm trying to declare the protocol conformance.  Removing the protocol conformance compiles without errors, but obviously doesn't help the case.

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or if Swift simply can't (or doesn't want to) support what I'm trying to do.  Even if I simply define the extension, then try to take care of the conformance in the body, it produces the risk of passing sequences that don't really conform to what they should.

At best it's a hacky solution to just fail in cases where a sequence with non-conforming members are passed.  I'd much rather let the compiler prevent it from happening.

(This is in Swift 2.1, Xcode 7.1.1)

Comment: The idea of this framework is pretty good. Please let me know if you publish it.

Comment: IIRC we cannot yet implement protocol extensions on generics with constraints :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the protocol conformance, unfortunately.